# Can't retrieve data from Firebase. App closes the fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't retrieve data from **Firebase** in a `Fragment`. In the same `Fragment` I can save data to **Firebase**, but can't retrieve them. Then I open the `Fragment` to read data, it crashes.

I use `docRef` for retrieving and `databaseDocumente` to save data.

```
 FirebaseDatabase docDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference docRef = docDatabase.getReference();
    userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    docRef.child("Docs").child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

            for (DataSnapshot child : children){
                Docum doc = child.getValue(Docum.class);

                itp1.setText(doc.dataitp1);
                itp2.setText(doc.dataitp2);
                rca1.setText(doc.datarca1);
                rca2.setText(doc.datarca2);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



    final DatabaseReference databaseDocumente;
    userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    databaseDocumente = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Docs");

    salveaza = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.buttonsalveazadoc);
    salveaza.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            adaugaDate();

        }

            private void adaugaDate(){
            String ditp1 = (String) itp1.getText().toString();
            String ditp2 = (String) itp2.getText().toString();
            String drca1 = (String) rca1.getText().toString();
            String drca2 = (String) rca2.getText().toString();
            String drov1 = (String) rov1.getText().toString();
            String drov2 = (String) rov2.getText().toString();
            String dmed1 = (String) med1.getText().toString();
            String dmed2 = (String) med2.getText().toString();
            String dsting1 = (String) sting1.getText().toString();
            String dsting2 = (String) sting2.getText().toString();

                if((!TextUtils.isEmpty(ditp2))&&(!TextUtils.isEmpty(drca2))){
                    String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();

                    Docum documente = new Documd(itp1,ditp2,drca1,drca2,drov1,drov2,dmed1,dmed2,dsting1,dsting2);

                    databaseDocumente.child(userID).setValue(documente);


                        Toast.makeText(myView.getContext(), "Date salvate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                        Toast.makeText(myView.getContext(), "Introduceti toate datele", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
        }
    });

    return myView;
}
}
```

I followed tutorials but I didn't succeed. I did something similar in another `Fragment` and was okay. Here i did the same thing but it crashes. If I use:

```
docRef.child(userId).addValueEventListener
```

instead of:

```
docRef.child("Docs").child(userId).addValueEventListener
```

the fragment doesn't crash, but the fields are still empty. 
Thank you!

This is the logcat: [LOG](https://textuploader.com/dzi68)

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Just the fragment crashes. The app is running in MainActivity after that.

Comment: userId might be null. You must sigin the app before get the current user.

Comment: @matio tried it. Same result

Comment: Please include the (relevant part of the) logcat in your question as text instead of a link.

Comment: show us your db structure

Comment: Resolved, I will add the code as soon I  will be home.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. This is the working code:

```
 FirebaseDatabase docDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference docRef = docDatabase.getReference();
    userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    docRef.child("docs").child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Docum doc = dataSnapshot.getValue(Docum.class);

                itp1.setText(doc.dataitp1);
                itp2.setText(doc.dataitp2);
                rca1.setText(doc.datarca1);
                rca2.setText(doc.datarca2);
                rov1.setText(doc.datarov1);
                rov2.setText(doc.datarov2);
                med1.setText(doc.datamed1);
                med2.setText(doc.datamed2);
                sting1.setText(doc.datasting1);
                sting2.setText(doc.datasting2);
```

//                }
            }

```
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("firebaseerror", databaseError.toString());
        }
    });
```